# Security Exception when calling WCF Service from Sharepoint 2013 Visual webpart

Tags: security, wcf, service, exception

Want to call WCF service from Sharepoint 2013 Visual Web Part; when using this Service from Console it works perfectly.

I receive following Security Exception when using svc from webpart:

Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.WebPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

I´ve checked Sharepoint web.config file:

```
trust level="Full"  label -> Ok.
```

Web part Added to safe Controls -> Ok.

Add safe control in package configuration -> Ok.

What am i missing?

This is my code:

```
                using (Service1Client svc = new Service1Client(new BasicHttpBinding(),
                new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://xxxxxxxx/Service1.svc"))))
            {

                svc.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "domain";
                svc.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "user";
                svc.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "pass";

                Label1.Text = svc.GetData(123456); 
            }
```

I´m thinking about using JS and ajax to do the same. It is necessary to use a Full-trusted proxy for this?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sandbox Solutions are restricted from making calls to external web services. You could create a full-trust proxy or you could call the service from the client-side. If you choose client-side then you are going to need to use some kind of library (WebProxy, CORS) to get around the cross-domain restrictions enforced by the browser.

Comment: Thanks, i´ve finally managed it using trust proxy. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798427.aspx